# How to scale psycopg2 insert and select with single process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, scalability, psycopg2

It takes average of about `0.300095081329` for my insert to go through to finish commit to postgres.

Here is my table pattern

```
id_table
    latest_update_id (primary index)
    product_id       (index)
    publish_date

product_meta_table
    latest_update_id    (index)
    product_id          (index)
    meta_related_info1
    meta_related_info2
    ...etc

product_table
    latest_update_id    (index)
    product_id          (index)
    note_related_info1
    note_related_info2
    ....etc
```

Here are some of my inserts

```
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO id_table (product_id, publish_date)  \
             VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING latest_update_id",
    (my_dict["product_id"], my_dict["publish_date"])
)

 db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO product_table ( \
                   latest_update_id, \
                   product_id, \
                   note_related_info1, \
                   note_related_info2, \
                   ...etc)  \
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
    (my_dict["latest_update_id"], 
     my_dict["product_id"],
     my_dict["note_related_info1"],
     my_dict["note_related_info2"])
)
```

Using the insert time my throughput is about `1/0.3 = 3qps`

I know I can scale this horizontally by adding more instances but I want to try to see if I can hit at least `3000qps`.

I am thinking of either using aync or threading, but was not sure of `GIL` is going to interfere or not.

Is there a general good practice and technique on how to scale `insert` statements using psycopg2?

Thanks

Note: I am using python 2.7

Note: python process is communicating with sql server through https

Note: the inserts to each table are staggered, table2 inserts after table1, table3 inserts after table2. Technically table2 and table3 only have to wait for table1 to finish insert because they need `latest_update_id`

Comment: I think multithreading can be useful here, as this is more of an I/O task, where GIL doesn't cause troubles.

Comment: I think you should be able to bring that up substantially before you have to do multihreading or anything particularly fancy. 3 qps is abysmal.

Comment: More specifically, if you're getting 3 inserts/sec something else is going horribly wrong. You should edit your question to describe what you're trying to accomplish in general and provide other details - is this a bulk insert thing? Something else? Why the 'returning'? How are you measuring the time? Have you profiled your code? etc.

Comment: Suspect network issue here. How long does "SELECT 1" take? What is ping time to server? Is Autocommit ON?

Comment: @peufeu `Select 1` took `0.170562982559` seconds. So I think network is indeed the issue, since I did 3 inserts that are staggered  `0.300095081329` is not unreasonable. Not sure how to check or improve ping time to server. `Autocommit` is not on, I commit after the 3 inserts to each table are done.

Comment: OK, next try ping, just in case, but I think you've found the problem. If you want high-throughput the database and client machine should be in the same datacenter with big fast network bandwidth between them...

Comment: @pvg  I need to return  `latest_update_id` because insert for `product_meta_table` and `product_table` needs it. Time is measured through `start = time.time() end = time.time() print(end - start)`

Comment: @peufeu I don't think I can ping since I am using amazon RDS. RDS seems to not respond to ping according to docs

Comment: @user3591466 you should post something closer to [MCVE] and include your timing code, that way anyone could have trivially tried it and noticed you are probably hosting your RDBMS behind a 14.4k modem in a basement in Ulan Bator.

Answer (score 2):

Do a single insert query in instead of 3. Notice the triple quotes and dictionary parameter passing:

```
insert_query = """
    with i as (
        insert into id_table (product_id, publish_date) 
        values (%(product_id)s, %(publish_date)s)
        returning latest_update_id
    )
    insert into product_table (
        latest_update_id,
        product_id,
        note_related_info1,
        note_related_info2
    ) values (
        (select latest_update_id from i),
        %(product_id)s, %(note_related_info1)s, %(note_related_info2)s
    )
    returning *
"""

db_cursor.execute(insert_query, my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Followup on my network comment.

Say you have 100ms roundtrip (like the time for SELECT 1).

If you want to chain queries, then you will have no other choice than to do INSERT... with tons of values to amortize the roundtrip time.

This is cumbersome, as you then will have to sort through the returned ids, to insert the dependent rows. Also, if your bandwidth is low, you will saturate it, and it won't be that fast anyway.

If your bandwidth is high enough but your ping is slow, you may be tempted to multithread... but this creates another problem...

Instead of having, say 1-2 server process churning through queries very fast, you'll have 50 processes sitting there doing nothing except waste valuable server RAM while they wait for the queries to come over the slow network.

Also, concurrency and lock issues may arise. You won't do just INSERTs... You're going to do some SELECT FOR UPDATE which grabs a lock...

...and then other processes pile up to acquire that lock while your next query crawls over the network...

This feels like using MyISAM in a concurrent write-intensive scenario. Locks should be held for the shortest time possible... fast pings help, putting the whole chain of queries from lock acquisition to release lock inside a stored proc is even better, so it is held for only a very short time.

So, consider executing your python script on the DB server, or on a server on the same LAN.